# Function to edit data on "comment_count" column on WordPress "wp_posts" DB table

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

What function should I use to edit content of `comment_count` column on wp_posts table? Example: when updating a post (with WP All Import), I want set the post's `comment_count` to any desired number.

Currently, WP All Import custom file uses its `offer_thumbs_down` data field to:

```
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'offer_thumbs_down', $data['offer_thumbs_down'] );
```

I want send `offer_thumbs_down` value to `wp_posts > comment_count` instead.

The purpose is to use `comment_count` as orderby
('orderby' => 'comment_count') because sorting huge number of posts by meta or custom fields is being a very slow SQL query. Using columns from `wp_post` table (post_date, post_title, comment_count, etc) has much better performance for `orderby`. Native comments are deactivated and useless for me, so I can use that field to hold other data and use it to orderby. I saw WordPress function `wp_update_comment_count_now( $post_id );` but this is not for inserting data, is just to make WP count comments byitself.

Comment: I found this code on other article but can't adapt it to work. Anyone know how? `$wpdb->query("UPDATE wp_posts SET comment_count = '$comment_count' WHERE ID = '$post_id'");`

Comment: Tried this adapted version, but failed: Fatal error: syntax error, unexpected ''  `$wpdb->query("UPDATE wp_posts SET comment_count = '$data['offer_thumbs_down']' WHERE ID = '$post_id'");`